# Empty dashboard for not ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN user (symfony2, sonata acl)

Tags: symfony, sonata

I use ACL in Sonata Admin Bundle. Аnd when I log in as a *root* (which has ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN) I can  create new users. I've created one (named *qwer*) and then loged in as *qwer*.

PROBLEM: in my situation *qwer* user has empty dashbord, even having roles like

`ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_GUEST, ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_STAFF, ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_EDITOR`

Please tell my -- what should I do to understad where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow [the documentation for ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html) fully? You should add your sonata_admin configuration and `security.yml` just to be sure. Mine looks like:

```
sonata_admin:
    # ...
    security:
        handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl
        # acl security information
        information:
            LIST:     [LIST]
            GUEST:    [VIEW, LIST]
            STAFF:    [LIST, CREATE]
            EDITOR:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT, EDIT]
            ADMIN:    [MASTER]
        admin_permissions: [CREATE, LIST, DELETE, UNDELETE, EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER]
        # permission related to the objects
        object_permissions: [VIEW, EDIT, DELETE, UNDELETE, OPERATOR, MASTER, OWNER]
```

Also ensure your `security.yml` has the required configuration:

```
security:
    # ...
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
    acl:
        connection: default
    access_decision_manager:
        strategy: unanimous
```

And add a PermissionMap to your `app/config/parameters.yml` or bundle parameters:

```
# src/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

parameters:
    # ...
    # Symfony 3 and above
    security.acl.permission.map:
      class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap

    # Symfony < 3
    security.acl.permission.map.class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap
```

Then there are 3 commands you will need to run:

Initialize your ACL setup (only once)

`php app/console init:acl`

Reload changes to the configuration (every change in the sonata_admin configuration file)

`php app/console sonata:admin:setup-acl`

To generate (new) ACL rules for already existing entities/objects. (every change in the sonata_admin configuration file)

`php app/console sonata:admin:generate-object-acl`

Then once the configuration is setup, logout and log back in again for the roles to apply.

Comment: thank you! I found solution by adding in my  such lines: `services:
    security.acl.permission.map:
        class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap
 
parameters:`  like here: http://fkn.ktu10.com/?q=node/8737

Comment: Oh you're right I do have a line similar to that in my `parameters.yml`. Totally missed it. I will edit the answer with your input.

Answer (score 0):

to resolve this problem check that your have in  of your app bundle lines:

```
services:
    security.acl.permission.map:
        class: Sonata\AdminBundle\Security\Acl\Permission\AdminPermissionMap

parameters:
```